# Undefined index , Unable to fetch columns- Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-8

```
 $notification=Notifications::where('status','false')->get();
 $data=$notification->all();
 //dd($data);
 dd($data['notificationTypeName']);
```

In the above code, `Notifications` is the model Name. Getting the error `Undefined index: notificationTypeName` when trying to access column `notificationTypeName` of the array `$data`.

`dd($data)` gives an ouput as below:

```
array:4 [
  0 => App\Models\Notifications {#323
    #table: "notifications"
    #fillable: array:6 [
      0 => "notificationTypesId"
      1 => "notificationTypeName"
      2 => "userId"
      3 => "email"
      4 => "status"
      5 => "recipientName"
    ]
    #connection: "pgsql"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    +preventsLazyLoading: false
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:9 [
      "id" => 5
      "notificationTypesId" => 3
      "notificationTypeName" => "Cart Expired"
      "userId" => 1
      "email" => "me.g@k.com"
      "recipientName" => "John"
      "status" => false
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
    ]
    #original: array:9 [
      "id" => 5
      "notificationTypesId" => 3
      "notificationTypeName" => "Cart Expired"
      "userId" => 1
      "email" => "me.g@k.com"
      "recipientName" => "John"
      "status" => false
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
    ]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #classCastCache: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [
      0 => "*"
    ]
    #enableLoggingModelsEvents: true
    #oldAttributes: []
  }
```

Comment: use foreach for getting data from object

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh I need to fetch column without using foreach ,becoz i need all the rows from db at the ouput in every fetch. That's the issue am facing.

Comment: try  with  `dd($data[0]['notificationTypeName']);`

Comment: In $notification how many records are coming is it single or multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `all` method returns the underlying array represented by the collection:

see this : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-all

so try with this:

```
 dd($data[0]['notificationTypeName']) // if u r not going to use foreach
```

with `foreach`

```
foreach( $notifications as $notification)
{
  dd($notification->notificationTypeName);
}
```

Comment: This works. But i've one other line like `tap($data)->update(['status'=>'true']);` in my code. Now this code shows the error `Call to a member function update() on array`

Comment: try with `tap($data[0])` with specific index but i would suggest to use `foreach` or better find notification by `id` if u do not want foreach